How to remap the PrtSc key so that PrtSc is another AltGr key?
My Thinkpad P52 sadly has a German keyboard so when I do not have an extra UK keyboard attached to it, I need to press AltGr right beside the space key plus e.g. 7 to get "{"
Idiotically, Lenovo has placed the PrtSc key right beside the AltGr key so often, instead of hitting AltGr I hit PrtSc.
To avoid this I would like to assign the "AltGr" function to the PrtSc key but keep it also for the AltGr key.
The PrtSc function can be completely removed or assigned to some other useless key on the keyboard, e.g. Numpad-slash
I am using the MATE windows manager under Ubuntu 24.04
Is there a way to do this either in the GUI, through changing of config files or by running some commands at login time?
I did not find anything in the Cotrol Center -- KeyboardShortcuts dialog that would work.
Also, if I then switch to the UK keyboard layout after attaching my extra UK keyboard will whatever I have done for the German keyboard undone?
